# How to fail a test in pre-request script in Postman due to some condition and not hitting the API?

Tags: javascript, testing, postman, newman, postman-collection-runner

How can I fail a test in a pre-request script in Postman due to some condition and not hitting the API?

If some condition is not satisfying, I need to fail the test case, and for that API, I don't want to run that API and proceed to the next API.

For example:

I want to write a condition in pre-request,

If that pre-request is satisfied, only then should we hit the API and validate.

Otherwise, it should fail the test without hitting the API and continue to the next test.

Answer (score -2):

There is a possibility that you can stop the workflow execution if all the Pre-Conditions are not met in Postman.

There is a postman function which you can use in the pre-conditions tab.

```
if(all pre conditions are not met){
   postman.setNextRequest(null);
}
```

`postman.setNextRequest(null)` would stop the workflow execution

You would get more information [here](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/scripts/branching_and_looping#collapse-category-0-4)

Comment: above comment stops execution, but does not fail the test.